# vim auto indenting lines without semicolons in Ruby

Tags: ruby, vim, indentation

For some reason, in vim whenever there is a line of ruby code with a function including parentheses, eg: `string = gets()` without a semicolon the next line is indented a level. When there is a semicolon, it works fine. Any ideas as to why this is happening and how to fix it? Also, since it will probably be requested, [here is my `~/.vimrc`](https://gist.github.com/52ec22185d41736556f6)

Comment: `gets()` works without brackets.

Comment: I know, but that was just as an example, it does the same for other things with parentheses.

Comment: the gist has been deleted, which means that the question, and answer are now just wasted time for anyone with the same problem. :/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably don't want `set cindent` on ruby files.

Use `au FileType ruby setlocal nocindent`

At the top (before any other au's) for other languages to work properly you need

instead of their respective lines.

Comment: @Mark Szymanski - It will break cindent if you try to edit a C file after a Ruby file you need that first line of the last 2.

Comment: I will, once the time limit is up :P

Comment: I just realized that I was confusing `autoindent` with `smartindent`. To be clear `smartindent` might cause some problems with Ruby - if it does, do the same thing I did with `cindent` to `smartindent`.

Comment: Do not suggest using two different autocommands. Use `setlocal` for doing buffer-local changes. It will eliminate the need of the second autocommand.

Comment: while we're at it, if you really /do/ want to use `cindent`, `:set cinoptions=+0` should help.